# Custom progress bar with goals

Tags: swift, xcode, progress-bar

I have almost no experience related to animations and I want some pointers about what is the right approach and what UI objects to use to start building a custom progress view with goals, for video content, example:
[image]

Some ideias I already had:

Use an horizontal collection view for all the elements, each cell is a progress bar?

Use a stack view?

Answer (score -1):

One regular progress bar with imageviews laid over the top (horizontal stack with spacers).  Images would update depending on current point of video playback